# Generate all n-bit binary bit patterns in order of their sum

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I need a generator that yields every bit pattern of *n* bits in order of their sum (and more). For example for *n=3*,

```
1. sum([0, 0, 0]) = 0 ✓
2. sum([1, 0, 0]) = 1 ✓
3. sum([0, 1, 0]) = 1 ✓
4. sum([1, 1, 0]) = 2 ⨯  should be swapped with 5.
5. sum([0, 0, 1]) = 1 ⨯
6. sum([1, 0, 1]) = 2 ✓
7. sum([0, 1, 1]) = 2 ✓
8. sum([1, 1, 1]) = 3 ✓
```

Note that even though 3 and 5 have the same sum, 5 should be generated after 3. The correct order would have been, `000, 100, 010, 001, 110, 101, 011, 111`. The idea here is that if this `(2ⁿ, n)` dimension matrix was multiplied by a `(n, 1)` vector that is sorted in ascending order than the product would be sorted as well. Eliminating the need to sort this product will help in optimising an experiment I am trying to run.

Here is my rather inefficient and incomplete attempt,

```py
def forwards(n):
    ls = [0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i):
            copy = list(ls)
            copy[j] = 1
            yield copy
        ls[-(i+1)] = 1
```

As you can see, this does get the order right but misses some patterns.

Here is another somewhat efficient but wrong order attempt.

```py
def forwards(n):
    for i in range(1 << n):
        yield [(i >> k) & 1 for k in range(n)]
```

This one generates all patterns but in the wrong (shown in the example above) order.

I need this function to be efficient so solutions where a string is generated and then characters are converted to integers are discouraged.

Lastly, I am working in Python 3.9. You can use Numpy.

Comment: Can you provide the sequence for 4 bits to make it clear? i.e. 0000,....,1111

Comment: Do you really need a generator?  `sorted(product([0,1], repeat=20),key=sum)`  creatse what you want for 1M items for an upfront cost of <.8s on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this gives you the order you want:

1. First, sort in ascending order by number of 1's
2. Next, sort in descending order by lexicographical order

```
from itertools import combinations 

def forwards(n):
  for one_bits in range(n + 1):
    for combination in combinations(range(n), one_bits):
      yield [1 if x in combination else 0 for x in range(n)]

for x in forwards(4):
  print("{}, one bits = {}, binary value = {}".format(x, sum(x), sum(x[i] * 2**(3 - i) for i in range(4))))
```

This works by handling the first condition in the first for loop `for one_bits in range(n + 1):`, and generating all possible N-sized combinations of indices between `0` and `n - 1`, and then those indices are set to 1, else 0.

This prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0], one bits = 0, binary value = 0
[1, 0, 0, 0], one bits = 1, binary value = 8
[0, 1, 0, 0], one bits = 1, binary value = 4
[0, 0, 1, 0], one bits = 1, binary value = 2
[0, 0, 0, 1], one bits = 1, binary value = 1
[1, 1, 0, 0], one bits = 2, binary value = 12
[1, 0, 1, 0], one bits = 2, binary value = 10
[1, 0, 0, 1], one bits = 2, binary value = 9
[0, 1, 1, 0], one bits = 2, binary value = 6
[0, 1, 0, 1], one bits = 2, binary value = 5
[0, 0, 1, 1], one bits = 2, binary value = 3
[1, 1, 1, 0], one bits = 3, binary value = 14
[1, 1, 0, 1], one bits = 3, binary value = 13
[1, 0, 1, 1], one bits = 3, binary value = 11
[0, 1, 1, 1], one bits = 3, binary value = 7
[1, 1, 1, 1], one bits = 4, binary value = 15
```